# Windows 10 stuck on please wait - cannot boot

Tags: windows-10

My laptop suddenly won't boot, and gets stuck on "Please wait". I've found numerous threads online dealing with the same issue and followed all the steps in each one and still cannot boot. I can boot in safe mode and did so, installed all the latest windows updates and updated my drivers but still cannot boot. I enable boot log and can see it has to do with my graphics driver (below the part of the boot log where things start to loop and not load). It basically loops on these errors forever. I managed to boot once or twice after leaving it on boot for hours, but then whenever the laptop went to sleep mode, it was once again not loading...

Can somebody help me figure out what's wrong?

```
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem42.inf,%devicename%;spacedesk Graphics Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @hal.inf,%acpi_amd64.devicedesc%;ACPI x64-based PC
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem124.inf,%nvvad_waveextensible.devicedesc%;NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem97.inf,%xsplit_dummy.devicedesc%;XSplit  Stream  Audio  Renderer
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem42.inf,%devicename%;spacedesk Graphics Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem124.inf,%nvvad_waveextensible.devicedesc%;NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)


BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem97.inf,%xsplit_dummy.devicedesc%;XSplit  Stream  Audio  Renderer
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem42.inf,%devicename%;spacedesk Graphics Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor


BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cmbatt.inf,%acpi\acpi0003.devicedesc%;Microsoft AC Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cmbatt.inf,%acpi\pnp0c0a.devicedesc%;Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor

BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem42.inf,%devicename%;spacedesk Graphics Adapter
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @oem74.inf,%ibdwhalogt2%;Intel(R) HD Graphics 5600
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED @cpu.inf,%intelppm.devicedesc%;Intel Processor
```

Comment: First boot and then quickly press power button or cut off power supply before the appearance of "Please wait" and immediately after if you hear boot beep sound. Repeat this three times. Then automatic startup repair will start. Let that complete and check if your problem solves. If that does not work insert installation media and click Repair your computer. Now try System restore. If you don't mind uninstalling recently installed programs then you can Reset your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already did startup repair several times, even reset the pc and still not booting... Laptop is MSI and came preinstall with no CD or anything. I do have a Linux dual-boot so in case I need to reinstall Windows I can back up my data but I really would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: Then you have to reinstall Windows (if you even don't like). Backup your data elsewhere and perform reinstallation.

Comment: You can also restore from your last disk image.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no disk image available (that's a good lesson for next time)... Reinstalling did work, so I guess problem solved.